# Vue.js Push and the back button

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of items in a Vue.js template. The user starts at '/list', which is a list of items. When an item is clicked, I use $router.push to send the user to a route. The route I send the user to is:

```
$router.push('/items/[theItemId]/Property1');
```

I do this so the user doesn't have to ever be on ' /items/[theItemId]'. This is working great, however when the user hits the back button, they are taken to the route:

```
/items/[theItemId]
```

I instead want the user to be directed back to the main list.

```
'/list'
```

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: There must be more to the story than this. There's no reason it would ever go to `/items/[theItemId]` using the back button unless you went there, clicked another link, and clicked the back button.

Comment: I have entered an answer below (too long for a comment), assuming a few things. If my assumption is not correct (regarding the programmatic navigation in mounted hook), please provide more info so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear in my original question. Mani's answer is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are using `$router.push` in the `created` or `mounted` hook of your route component for `/items/:itemID`.

When you use `$router.push`, a new item in history stack gets created. So your history stack now looks as follows:

`/list` >> `/items/:itemID` >> `/items/:itemID/Property1`

As the back button generally takes you to the previous entry in your history stack, it takes you to `/items/:itemID` as expected.

To avoid this, you may use `$router.replace` instead of `$router.push` as explained here:

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Quoted from the page above:

> **router.replace(location)**
>
> It acts like `router.push`, the only difference is that it navigates without pushing a new history entry, as its name suggests - it replaces the current entry.

If you use `$router.replace`, your history stack now will be:

`/list` >> `/items/:itemID/Property1`

Now if you hit the back button, you will end up in `/list`.